# CSV file aggregator (appender) CLI

Tags: rust, csv

My goal is to write a  CLI utility that aggregate (appends) many CSV files in a lightweight and performant (my use-case involves output files in the 10s of GBs) manner.

Specifically, the utility should look for CSV files of a provided filename in one or more provided directories, aggregating all contents into a single output CSV file. The extra functionality is that the directory name should be added to the output CSV file as an extra column to indicate where a specific row originated from.

It can be expected that every CSV file has the same headers (in the same order).

The ErrorMode enum (passed via `--error`) should indicate whether the program panics or silently errors (skips) when the file is not found in a folder.

I'm treating this as a way to teach myself Rust; this is the first real project I've made in the language.

Originally (pre-edit), I wrote to the output file multiple times (once for the header, and once per folder). I've since tried to refactor the code to collect the output contents in a `Vec<String>` and perform one write operation at the end, which seems to have made a substantial improvement on execution time.

```rust
use clap::{ArgEnum, Parser};
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{prelude::*, BufReader, BufWriter, ErrorKind};
use std::path::Path;

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, ArgEnum)]
enum ErrorMode {
    Panic,
    Skip,
}

#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
#[clap(author, version, about, long_about = None)]
struct Args {
    #[clap(short, long)]
    filename: String,

    #[clap(short = 'F', long)]
    folders: String,

    #[clap(short, long)]
    column: String,

    #[clap(short, long, default_value = "./")]
    root: String,

    #[clap(short, long, default_value = "output.csv")]
    output: String,

    #[clap(short, long)]
    verbose: bool,

    #[clap(short, long, arg_enum, default_value = "panic")]
    error: ErrorMode,
}

fn main() {
    let args = Args::parse();

    // Create output file that all inputs will be aggregated into
    let out = match File::create(args.output.clone()) {
        Ok(file) => file,
        Err(err) => match err.kind() {
            ErrorKind::PermissionDenied => {
                panic!("Permission denied when trying to create output file!")
            }
            other => panic!(
                "Encountered an error when creating output file: {:?}",
                other
            ),
        },
    };

    let mut out = BufWriter::new(out);
    let mut lines: Vec<String> = Vec::new();

    // Expect folder names to be comma-delimited
    for (i, folder) in args.folders.split(',').enumerate() {
        let path = Path::new(&args.root).join(folder).join(&args.filename);

        let file = match File::open(path) {
            Ok(file) => file,
            Err(err) => match err.kind() {
                ErrorKind::NotFound => {
                    // Skip files that don't exist if `--error=skip`
                    if args.error == ErrorMode::Skip {
                        if args.verbose {
                            println!("Couldn't find file in folder '{}', so skipping...", folder);
                        }
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        panic!("Couldn't find file in folder '{}'!", folder)
                    }
                }
                ErrorKind::PermissionDenied => panic!(
                    "Permission denied when trying to read file in folder '{}'!",
                    folder
                ),
                other => panic!(
                    "Encountered an error when reading file in folder '{}': {:?}",
                    folder, other
                ),
            },
        };
        let mut reader = BufReader::new(file);

        // Read the header, but only include if on first iteration (to avoid dupes)
        let mut header = String::new();
        reader
            .read_line(&mut header)
            .unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("Failed to read header from file in folder '{}'!", folder));
        if i == 0 {
            lines.extend_from_slice(vec![
                args.column.clone(),
                ",".to_owned(),
                header.replace("\r\n", ""),
                "\n".to_owned(),
            ].as_slice());
        }

        for line in reader.lines().filter_map(|result| result.ok()) {
            lines.extend_from_slice(vec![folder.to_owned(), ",".to_owned(), line, "\n".to_owned()].as_slice());
        }
    }

    out.write_all(lines.join("").as_bytes())
        .expect("Failed to write to output file!");
}
```

**Example**

Given the following inputs:

```
-f "in.csv" -F "a,b,c" -c "folder" -o "out.csv"
```

And the following folder structure:

```
- a
  - in.csv
- b
  - in.csv
- c
  - hello.csv
```

The contents of `a/in.csv` and `b/in.csv` would be aggregated to `out.csv` (`c/` would be ignored, rather than raise an error). An extra column named `folder` would be present in the output file: its value would be `a` for all rows that came from `a/in.csv` and `b` for those that came from `b/in.csv`.

**Edit**

I've since discovered a bug in my code: by using the folder iteration number to determine whether or not to write the header, this causes the header to be omitted from the output entirely if the first file is not found (and thus skipped silently with `--error=skip`). Aside from this, the code is entirely functional.